# Dynamic lable between two lable is not correctly displayed before scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, cell

I have this situation 
[uilable](dynamic width)-[uilable](dynamic height)-[uilable](dynamic width). 
Of course I use auto layout . at the first loading the table is displayed not correctly.  What is problem ?

before
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenrfr.png
after
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screennvn.png

Comment: Did you check contentHuggingPriority. Set middle label priority more than other two label. As autolayout will calculate middle label height based on first label and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check contentHuggingPriority. Set middle label priority more than other two label. As autolayout will calculate middle label height based on first label and so on.

For your table loading problem for the first time, set middle label height constraint >= i.e. 60px >=.

Comment: I set mid lable 1000 contentHuggingPriority for vertical and 250 for horizontal . it's doesn't work . Now i set mid table  >= height , but cell doesn't change height .

Comment: @КристианМолер can you share screenshot of your constraints and value. it might give idea.

Comment: yes i can 
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenchc.png
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenpmp.png
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenjqj.png
http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenuwu.png

Comment: @КристианМолер from the second screen shot i saw that you haven't set vertical constraint between middle label bottom to its parentview bottom. Can you set and let me know.

Comment: And are you calculating cell height and providing this value in tableview height for row at index path or you have set UItableviewRowAutomaticDimention in tableview.rowheight.

Comment: oh ...  i add vertical constraint . Yes i use  UItableviewRowAutomaticDimention . now lable doesn't calculate height before scroll again . http://img.uzsat.net/?v=screenhlh.png

Comment: just to make sure, is middle label, number of line property, set to 0 or not.?

Comment: I fix it . I change font size in code . It was problem  =)